# Simple problem solvable with Bethe ansatz

Tags: quantum-mechanics, integrable-systems, spin-chains

I want some exercise for my students. Is there any simple but still non-trivial problem which can be solved with Bethe ansatz? The Heisenberg model is still too heavy.

Comment: I would look at the Hubbard model, which is a tight binding Ising chain type of problem. The Yang Baxter equation is also a case of this ansatz.

Comment: This appears to be a list-based question, which is generally considered off topic because it is *too broad*.

Comment: @KyleKanos I agree, but think that the list of examples of models solvable by Bethe ansatz *simpler* than the Heisenberg model might be rather short, and personally would be interested to see further examples

Answer (score 3):

Here is one example. The book [Quantum Inverse Scattering Method and Correlation Functions](http://www.cambridge.org/se/academic/subjects/physics/theoretical-physics-and-mathematical-physics/quantum-inverse-scattering-method-and-correlation-functions?format=PB) by Korepin, Bogoliubov and Izergin introduces the coordinate Bethe ansatz first for the 1d Bose gas (Chapter I.1), with wave function governed by the *non-linear Schrödinger equation*
 $$i \ \partial_t \Psi = -\partial_x^2 \Psi + 2\ c\ |\Psi|^2 \ \Psi \ ,$$
which is very closely related to the [Lieb--Liniger model](http://scholarpedia.org/article/Lieb-Liniger_model_of_a_Bose_Gas), with delta-function potential, and is also related to [experiments](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v440/n7086/full/nature04693.html). The two-body S-matrix is just rational in the rapidities, the Bethe have only real solutions, etc. The solutions and resulting thermodynamics was studied in detail by Yang and Yang.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: But as an exercise, it is still too lengthy, I am afraid.

Comment: @senator I'd say that depends on the amount of hints. (I would not include anything about the thermodynamics in an exercise.)

Answer (score 2):

How about a *two-particle* problem? See the model in this paper [Tamm-Hubbard surface states in the continuum](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0658). The model is very simple but not so trivial. It is also a beautiful model as it can be solved exactly by Bethe ansatz---Bethe ansatz in the baby form. I think it can make a very good exercise in solid state physics.

It is a variant of the model in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.6431), which is also very simple, but is only semi-solvable in the sense that only half of the states conform to the Bethe ansatz.

So you get at least two good exercises.